# Passing data to ConrainerView from ViewControlller always nil

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have CurrentYearViewController in that I used container to show multiple views. The problem is value that I am sending to ContainerViewController is getting always `nil`

**CurrentYearViewController**

```
//calling this function after getting response, not presenting because it is called from Segmented Control 

func refreshCurrentYearListView(dict: NSDictionary) {
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let containerViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "containerView") as!
    ContainerViewController
    containerViewController.dataDictionary = dict
}
```

**ContainerViewController**

```
class ContainerViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var billedValueLbl: UILabel!
  var dataDictionary: NSDictionary!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


  }

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    if let data = dataDictionary {
        populateJSON(dict: data)
    }
  }

  func populateJSON(dict: NSDictionary) {

    let N_A: String = "N/A"
    let parser = CommonParser()

    let currentYearSalesSummaryDict: NSDictionary = parser.parse(dictionary: dict, key: "currentYearInvoiceSummary")
    if currentYearSalesSummaryDict.count > 0 {
        billedValueLbl.text = parser.parse(dictionary: currentYearSalesSummaryDict, key: "totalInvoiceAmount", exceptionString: N_A)
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure object `containerViewController ` is not nil.

Comment: @dahiya_boy thanks for reply, can u explain in detail?

Comment: You are creating a new instance of your contained view and setting he property on that.  You need a reference to the currently presented container view

Comment: @MinnuKaAnae paul is right. **Explanation :** Let be assume, you created the object of `ContainerViewController ` says object1 and passed the dict. Now when you call your refresh method then new object of `ContainerViewController` will be created says object2. Now, you've 2 objects of  `ContainerViewController`. How much you calls refresh func that much your object will be created. Better keep the reference of object1 and reuse it.

Comment: @MinnuKaAnae I am saying, Put the break point on the line ` containerViewController.dataDictionary = dict` and print in console `po containerViewController`. Now make sure printed value is not **nil**.

Comment: @dahiya_boy I tried print(containerViewController.dataDictionary = dict), in console it is showing data

Comment: @MinnuKaAnae Try this `print(containerViewController)`

Comment: @dahiya_boy not getting nil

Comment: @MinnuKaAnae Sounds good, check this also ->  In `ContainerViewController` , in `viewDidLoad` `print(dataDictionary)`

Comment: I tried here, dataDictionary getting nil

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174937/discussion-between-dahiya-boy-and-minnukaanae).